# How can I get occurrences and occurring positions in this series?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a value $N = 4$.

And I can generate a sequence of sets as follows {1} {1,2}, {2}, {1,2,3}, {2,3}, {3}, {1,2,3,4}, {2,3,4}, {3,4}, {4}

Is there an expression or formula that can tell me in how many sets of the sequence I can have for example {1,2}? 
    $3$ times from the sample

Is there a way to find the occurrence position(s) of {1,2} in the series? 
    positions $2,4,7$ from the sample.

**Added sequence details**

I really don't know how to express this mathematically but this is the pattern I am using.

If N is 3. then my possible set of values are 1,2,3

With that I am using a pattern that goes: for each value V generate set(s) containing items from 1 to max V where the number of each item cannot exceed V.

Taking 1: {1}
Taking 2: {1}, {2}, {1,2}
Taking 3: {1}, {2}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}, {2,3}, {3}

So as we progress, the previous ones are subsets of next one.

sets of 1 is a subset of sets of 2
sets of 1 and 2 are subsets of set 3

I can get the possible sets there is given N by N(N+1)/2 but still not sure how to get in how many sets have e.g 1,3 in them.

Comment: How are you generating the sequence of sets?

Comment: This is not clear.  It looks like you are just writing down the increasing subsequences of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ but it's not clear what order you have in mind.

Comment: I do not understand what you are getting at., but if I were to have written the sets in the question, I would not have chosen to write them in the order you have presented, but rather in the order $\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{2\},\{2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{3\},\{3,4\},\{4\}$ in a hopefully obvious way.  That, or in another order such as $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}$ in another obvious way.  If your question is "how many of these sets are there?" note that each set can be defined by choosing the lower bound and choosing the upper bound.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes it can be in that order. The lower bound is always 1 and the upper bound is N

Comment: There would be $n+\binom{n}{2}$ such sets (*corresponding to where lower and upper are the same vs when lower and upper are different*).  In the case of $n=4$ that would be $4+6=10$.  If you really are interested in "where in the sequence do sets with both $1$ and $2$ occur?"  then you really must decide on what that sequence *is* in the first place and explain it to us so that we might understand as it is not obvious.

Comment: @seth for your sequence, to get the position try $1 + \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for $n=1,2,3$

Comment: @JMoravitz I have  updated my question and tried explaining the sequence.